# Trigger on every update or insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create trigger that fires every time any column is changed - whether it is freshly updated or new insert. I created something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER textsearch
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger();
```

and body of trigger() function is:

```
BEGIN
   NEW.ts := (
    SELECT   COALESCE(a::text,'') || ' ' ||
             COALESCE(b::int,'')  || ' ' ||
             COALESCE(c::text,'') || ' ' ||
             COALESCE(d::int, '') || ' ' ||
             COALESCE(e::text,'')
    FROM    table
    WHERE   table.id = new.id);

   RETURN NEW;

END
```

I hope it is clear what I want to do.

My problem is that trigger fires only on update, not on insert. I guess that this isn't working because I have BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE, but if I change it to AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE then it doesn't work neither for INSERT nor UPDATE.

Comment: probably you need the [instead of insert trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I want to insert all data and concat all columns and save it in one other column.

Comment: Don't use `select`. Use the values from the `new` record directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name something like `NEW.ts = NEW.a || ' ' || NEW.b || ' ' || ... ?`

Comment: Correct. `concat_ws(' ', new.a, new.b, new.c, ...)` would be a bit shorter and handles NULLs properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `NEW` record directly:

```
BEGIN
   NEW.ts := concat_ws(' ', NEW.a::text, NEW.b::TEXT, NEW.c::TEXT);
   RETURN NEW;
END;
```

The advantage of `concat_ws` over `||` is that `concat_ws` will treat `NULL` values differently. The result of `'foo'||NULL` will yield `NULL` which is most probably not what you want. `concat_ws` will use an empty string `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're calling SELECT inside the function.

When it runs `BEFORE INSERT` then there isn't a row to select, is there?

Actually, `BEFORE UPDATE` you'll see the "old" version of the row anyway, won't it?

Just directly use the fields: `NEW.a` etc rather than selecting.

---

As an edit - here is an example showing what the trigger function can see. It's exaclty as you'd expect in a BEFORE trigger.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE tt (i int, t text, PRIMARY KEY (i));

CREATE FUNCTION trigfn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    sv text;
BEGIN
    SELECT t INTO sv FROM tt WHERE i = NEW.i;
    RAISE NOTICE 'new value = %, selected value = %', NEW.t, sv;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigtest BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tt FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigfn();

INSERT INTO tt VALUES (1,'a1');
UPDATE tt SET t = 'a2' WHERE i = 1;

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: @thecoparyew - I don't think you do. See edited version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your COALESCE statements when you cast b::int i had to change your coalesce to use integer place holder instead. As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name this can end up with null values but you can see how to make your specific code example run.  I included the "RAISE NOTICE" lines for debug purposes only.

Based on your provided information the following works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id SERIAL NOT NULL,a TEXT,b INTEGER,c TEXT,d INTEGER,e TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_triggered_procedure() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    if(TG_OP = 'UPDATE' OR TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        NEW.ts := (SELECT COALESCE(a::text,'') || ' ' ||
                          COALESCE(b::int,0) || ' ' || 
                          COALESCE(c::text,'') || ' ' || 
                          COALESCE(d::int, 0) || ' ' || 
                          COALESCE(e::text,'') 
                   FROM my_table 
                   WHERE id=NEW.id);         
        RAISE NOTICE 'INSERT OR UPDATE with new ts = %',NEW.ts;  
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        OLD.ts := ' ';        
        RAISE NOTICE 'DELETED old id: %',OLD.id;
        RETURN OLD;  
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER text_search 
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
 ON my_table
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_triggered_procedure();

INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES('text11',12,'text21',3,'text4');
>NOTICE:  INSERT OR UPDATE with new ts = text11 12 text21 3 text4
>INSERT 0 1

DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=24;
>NOTICE:  DELETED ID = 24
>DELETE 1
```

[PostgreSQL::Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Yeah, it fires but I don't know how to write function to update field value if I create AFTER trigger.

Comment: The `select` is totally unnecessary and makes the trigger *much* slower then it could be. Casting the columns to `int` also doesn't make sense as the integer value will immediately be cast to `text` due to it's usage in a `||` operator.

Comment: COALASCE function seems to get processed before the concat operator does. I'm just trying to make his code example work not change it or improve it or imprint my coding concepts.  The question wasn't on how to improve his code but how to make it run. IMO optimized code and functional code are two different animals. :)